# redirect vue page using node

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

im still learning js,vue,node and i stumble into this problem
i wanted to redirect vue page after i login using nodejs
this is my vue and the script

```
<form>
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="usernameEmailMobile">Username/Email/Mobile</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usernameEmailMobile" 
          placeholder="Enter username, email, or mobile number" required
          v-model="stateLogin.newInput" >
     </div>
     <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" 
          placeholder="Enter password" required
          v-model="stateLogin.passwordInput">
     </div>
     <button @click="login()" type="submit" class="btn btn-success ">Login</button>
</form>

<script>

import loginCRUD from '../modules/loginCRUD.js'

export default {
    name:"loginView",
    setup(){
        const {stateLogin, login} = loginCRUD()
        return {stateLogin, login}
    }
}
</script>
```

this is my module

```
import {reactive} from 'vue'

const doLogin =() =>{

    const stateLogin = reactive({
        newInput: '',
        passwordInput: ''
    })


    const login = () =>{
        const request = {
            method : "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json"
                //authtoken bisa disini
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                input: stateLogin.newInput ,
                password: stateLogin.passwordInput ,
            })
        }
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/user/login",
        request
        )
    }

    return {
        stateLogin,
        login
    }
}

export default doLogin
```

and this is my backend node

```
router.post('/login', async (req,res) =>{
    const tempUser = req.body.input;
    const password = req.body.password;
    
    // const user = await User.findOne({
    //     $or:
    //         [
    //             {username : tempUser},
    //             {mobilePhone : tempUser},
    //             {email : tempUser}
    //         ]
    // })
    const user = await User.findOne({username : tempUser })
    const worker = await Worker.findOne({username : tempUser })
    if(user != null){
        if(password == user.password){
           return res.redirect(301,`/home`)
        }else{
            
        }
    }else{

    }
    //const match = await bcrypt.cmopare(req.body.password, user.password)
})
```

i was able to get the data to my backend in node. it got to the point

```
if(password == user.password){
     return res.redirect(301,`/home`)
}
```

so if i put the correct password and match it to the password at the database it got to the inside if but it doesnt return and redirect to my home page view at vue

am i missing something?
thank you

Comment: You're trying to perform a server-side redirect in a client-side AJAX request. When you use ```res.redirect()``` in your node.js server, it works by sending a Location header to the client, instructing it to navigate to a new url. However, when this request is made via AJAX (which it is, since you're using the fetch API in your vue code), the browser doesn't automatically follow this redirect, instead, it simply returns the response to your js.

Comment: I guess submitting your form is doing the default action of submitting a form - in your case it `GET`s the current page - check your browser console to see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

try add "redirect: follow" like this

```
        const request = {
        method : "POST",
        redirect: 'follow',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" : "application/json"
            //authtoken bisa disini
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            input: stateLogin.newInput ,
            password: stateLogin.passwordInput ,
        })
    }
```

or can like this

```
 fetch(url, { method: 'POST' })
.then(response => {
    if (response.redirected) {
        window.location.href = response.url;
    }
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```